# Need help figuring out why xxx.catch isn't catching the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I'm on the edge of throwing my computer throught the window. I just can't see why this isn't working :

```
async function play(message, msg) {
    addytb(message, msg[3]).catch(err => {console.log('err');});
}

async function addytb(message, url) {
    ytbapi.getVideo(url)
    .then(video => {
        message.channel.send(`J'ai ajouté ${video.title} à la queue !`);
        queue.get(message.guild.id).push({"url": url, "type": 'youtube', "title": video.title});
    })
    .catch(() => {
        message.channel.send(`J'ai pas réussi à ajouter ça à la queue !`);
        throw 'error';
    });
}
```

I have been searching the internet for 2 hours and I can't find why I keep having unhandled promise warmings. I think this is because ytbapi.getVideo() is an async, but I don't know what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the `async` keyword and then using `.then` and `.catch` in the code?

Comment: I tryed several solutions and didn't remove the async before posting. I know they are not doing anything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is no need to use 'async' keyword with functions until and unless you are awaiting an asynchronous function inside it.
I've done some changes in the code, you can try:

```
function play(message, msg) {
    addytb(message, msg[3])
        .then((data) => {
            //do something with data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('err is: ', err);
        });
}

function addytb(message, url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ytbapi.getVideo(url)
            .then(video => {
                message.channel.send(`J'ai ajouté ${video.title} à la queue !`);
                queue.get(message.guild.id).push({
                    "url": url,
                    "type": 'youtube',
                    "title": video.title
                });
                resolve("success");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                message.channel.send(`J'ai pas réussi à ajouter ça à la queue !`);
                console.log(err)
                reject(err);
            });
    });
}
```

and if you really wanna try with async/await:

```
async function play(message, msg) {
    try {
        const data = await addytb(message, msg[3]);
        //do something with data
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err is: ', err);
    }
}

function addytb(message, url) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const video = await ytbapi.getVideo(url);
            message.channel.send(`J'ai ajouté ${video.title} à la queue !`);
            queue.get(message.guild.id).push({
                "url": url,
                "type": 'youtube',
                "title": video.title
            });
            resolve("success");
        } catch (err) {
            message.channel.send(`J'ai pas réussi à ajouter ça à la queue !`);
            console.log(err)
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

ps: you may need some modifications as i couldn't get a chance to try the code.
hope this helps :)